# Circularly polarized light reflected from a non-polarzing beam splitter

Tags: optics

Have anyone seen something similar like this in the lab?

[image]

When I input a left-circularly polarized (LCP) light to a non-polarzing beam splitter and check the chirality of both the transimitted and reflected beam. The transmitted beam are still left-circularly polarized light while the reflected beam seems to be right-circularly polarized (RCP). Note that both the beams are actually ellipticaly polarized, what I described might be over-simplified. Circularly polarized light were generated or analyzed with a combination of a linearly polarizer and a quarter-wave plate.

Could any one explain the detailed mechanism behind this? I mean adapt to the situation here, a non-polarizing beam splitter. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could analyze it by first treating the light as combinations of horizontal and vertical polarization. (Or you could just "hand-wave" and say that the reflected beam is mirrored so it must get the opposite circular polarization.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I mean there must be some phase shift in the s or p component. But how does this correlates to the structure of beam splitter? Is Fresenel equations enough to handle this case?